# How to Grant Folder Permissions to IIS Application

Tags: node.js, iis, networking, fs

I am trying to write out some files from a REST endpoint that is being served by IIS.  When writing to the local drive everything works smoothly. 
 However, when writing to a mapped drive, no files are created.

> Case 1 - Local - Working

```
outputOrderFilesLocal = (req, res, next) => {
fs.writeFile('./receipts/filename.txt', data, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err
  })
}
```

> Case 2 - Network - Broken

```
outputOrderFilesNetwork = (req, res, next) => {
fs.writeFile('Z:/receipts/filename.txt', data, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err
  })
}
```

I have set the folder permissions on the `Z:` drive to allow `NetworkService` and have changed the Application Pool identity to `NetworkService` in IIS.

Is it possible to write to a mapped drive?  Are there other permissions or configurations that need to be set to make this work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Z is a path defined at a user account level.  It maps to a specific network path, but only a certain user.  The account running for IIS probably doesn't have a definition for Z.

Instead, use the full UNC path of whatever Z is:

```
outputOrderFilesNetwork = (req, res, next) => {
fs.writeFile('\\\\uncservername\\uncserverpath\\receipts\\filename.txt', data, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err
  })
}
```

You'll further have to configure permissions for the account running the process on the UNC path, OS level permissions, as normally the IIS account wouldn't have those permissions.